# Microservices Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I am learning about microservices using Java technology (Spring Boot) , I can not find a good book or tutorials.
I want to learn about microservices in details.If any one can guide in this it will be great.

Comment: Watch the videos from Java Brains on YouTube. That is a great way to start if you don't have any experience in Java Spring Boot. Tutorials are really very helpful.

Comment: This is a great source to get started: https://microservices.io/.
Also microservices are nothing more than very small spring boot applications. The main idea is that each entity (for example customer) in the architecture has its own service.

Answer (score 1):

> https://spring.io/blog/2015/07/14/microservices-with-spring

Official spring blog has lots of resources